# Make double quotes from database value appear properly

Tags: html, css, sql-server-2008

I have a database type `varchar(100)`, the value contains double quotes `""`, for example:

> TCA CREAM 65 ML FC 24% “A Z A M”

I use sql server 2008.

When I call this data in my web page
the `""` can't be read.

The result looks like:

[image]

First I thought the font family was not supported, but I tried with many different font families:

```
html body div.popup_window_css div.popup_window_css_body {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-width: 0px 1px 0px 1px;
    padding: 6px 6px 0px 6px;
    background: #DBDBBA;
    width: 615px;
    font: 900 14px Trebuchet MS, Sans-Serif, Times New Roman;
    }
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: First of all, `"` is not the same as `“` or `”`. Secondly, have you set an encoding anywhere?

Comment: This is a classic text you might find interesting: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: ok tq, i found what the cause of this problem. solve it

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the quotes in your HTML to make this work.

Use javascript to convert these quotes, where you have your value:

```
var quoteString = myDbValue.replace('"', "&quot;");
```

Or try to turn any `"` into `&quot` any way you like.

From your comment:

```
success: function(data){ 
    $("#pname").replace('"', "&quot;"); 
    $("#pname").html(data); 
}
```

must change into:

```
success: function(data){ 
    escapedData = data.dbValue.replace('"', "&quot;"); 
    $("#pname").html(escapedData);
}
```

Of course I'm not exactly sure what `data` looks like in your code, but you should select the right property i.e. `dbValue` in my code.

Comment: this data i got using ajax
$(document).ready(function(){
  //apabila terjadi event onchange terhadap object <select id=pkategori>
  $("#pkategori").change(function(){
     var pkategori = $("#pkategori").val();
     $.ajax({
        url: "cariproduk.php",
        data: "pkategori="+pkategori,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
 $("#pname").html(data);
        }
        });
    });
  });
where i must convert the data

Comment: still not work,this script of "cariproduk.php"
//connect to database
$nama = $_GET['pkategori'];
$id = mssql_query("SELECT ProductName FROM tblMstProductUHT1 WHERE ProductCategory = '$nama'");
while($k = mssql_fetch_array($id)){
$p = $k[ProductName];
    echo "<option>$p</option>";
}
?>

Comment: `echo "<option>$p</option>"` > replace the quotes in your `p` variable.

Answer (score 1):

1. `",',-,_,>,>` kind of characters ([full list](http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html)) call special characters in HTML, because some of those may use to some other purpose in HTML/CSS/JS etc... So browsers not promise you to render this characters properly.
2. Some of this characters can use for break your web site by using SQL injection kind of method.

So best practice is before you store this characters  to database or before start to process, you have to convert this characters to their `HTML entity` using server side language (php,c#). By This you can avoid above both issues. you can find HTML entities in the link i given above.

Comment: -1 for "using server side language (php,c#)" > You can use javascript perfectly well.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester: funny, How do you avoid SQL injection using JavaScript ? JavaScript is ok for display purpose, but JavaScript ruining at client side. so one can avoid any time. requirement for use a server-side language is security purpose as well. If you can scarify security. Ok to use java-script in server cost seance

Comment: To begin with, security should be considered at **all** levels. You CAN avoid SQL injection in javascript by sanitising any string you send to the server. Secondly, this question has nothing to do with security at all. That's the OP's concern.

Comment: You have to keep remember users can avoid JS, no matter you do it how hard. As you know this can do both is client-side and server-side. I think every one looking for the best answer, not what ever the answer. I answer as my view.(though you bravely -1) . OP can select what is the answer he can use in his situation. Anyway, Thank you for your ideas. =)